# slices of H264 with various frame_number

Tags: numbers, frame, h.264, slice

I'm decoding a H264 video bit stream. I have PPS and SPS at first, after that is I slice, P,B,SI,SP slice. I used ffmpeg to convert it into mp4 format, but the video is not correct (it's playable but can't be seen clearly).

I think that my I-slice has been fragmented. Have you got any idea to merge them? In slices there are only frames-begin-with-0181 having frame_num from 1 to x. The other frames have non-sequency frame_num. What does that mean?

thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem. With the fragmented slices, I cut the header slices (example: 00000101) and only left the header of start slice (example: 00000181) and now I can convert to mp4 and watch the video :D